# Equivalent of FocusEvent.getOppositeComponent in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, focus

In my JavaFx application, I want to call a method when the main frame gains focus. However, I want to react only in the case where the focus was outside my application and came back (not when a dialog closes for example).

When the application was in Swing, I could use the method

```
FocusEvent.getOppositeComponent
```

(which corresponds to the element that lost focus), and if it was null I knew the focus was previously outside my application.

I have not found any equivalent in JavaFX.

I have tried looking at window events, by adding an event filter on my window:

```
primaryStage.addEventFilter(Event.ANY, e -> System.out.println("event " + e));
```

but it doesn't track focus events.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no equivalent in JavaFX. Focus changes are handled as a [boolean property](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Window.html#focusedProperty()) for each window separately, so you can only tell if a window received or lost focus. If you register a listener to all windows in your application, you could tell if one of them lost focus when another gained it.

There is no "FocusEvent" in JavaFX, you can find all event types listed in [`Event`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/event/Event.html).

You can request the feature [here](https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/).

Comment: Unfortunately, the `focused` property is not enough because the previous window loses focus before the next window gains it; in other words, there's a moment in time when none of the windows have focus (at least on the Java side) even when switching windows within the application. Otherwise my (deleted) answer would offer a valid solution.

Comment: That's pretty much what I figured out yes. I hoped some JavaFX guru would tell me to reflectively manipulate some obscure Skin class or internal class to solve my problem :-) I will suggest a change, though your link doesn't seem good to me, JavaFX isn't part of the JDK since Java 11 but all I've found is the openjfx mailing list. I'll try my luck there and keep you posted.

Comment: @Balderk You can submit through the link, JavaFX still uses the same databases and procedures set by Oracle, it's just that the jars are shipped separately. The mailing list is also a good possibility.

Comment: @user1803551 Ok, I thought they became completely independent. I sent an email to the mailing list with no luck. I'll try the issue tracker then.

Comment: Request submitted at https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8224744

Comment: @Balderk What do you mean "with no luck"? I watch the mailing list and didn't see an email on this subject. If you didn't subscribe, the owner will need to approve the mail, so that can take some time.

Comment: @user1803551 Sorry I meant with no luck so far. I subscribed after posting (I'm not the brightest man on Monday morning  ) and indeed my email seems stuck in someone's mail box waiting validation. Any way thanks for your help man.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a semi-satisfactory way of handling the problem, using the order of the events in JavaFX, so I'm posting it as an answer in case it can help others.

When a window w1 closes, giving focus to a window w2, the event order is as follow:

> 1. w1 receives event WINDOW_HIDING
> 2. w2 focusProperty changes to true
> 3. w1 receives event WINDOW_HIDDEN

So I wrote the following code to allow me to know whether the focus comes from an internal window:

```
public class MainStage {
    private Stage primaryStage;
    private AtomicBoolean triggerEventOnFocusGain = new AtomicBoolean(true);

    ...

    primaryStage.focusedProperty.addListener((prop, oldVal, newVal) -> {
        if(newVal.booleanValue() && triggerEventOnFocusGain.get()) {
            doStuff();
        }
    });
}

public class SomeDialog {
    private MainStage mainStage;
    private Window dialogWindow;

    ...

    dialogWindow.addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_HIDING, event ->
        mainStage.setTriggerEventOnFocusGain(false));
    dialogWindow.addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_HIDDEN, event ->
        mainStage.setTriggerEventOnFocusGain(true));
}
```

The only issue is that I have to do that for all internal windows/dialogs.

In my case I eventually decided that I could get away doing that for only a handful of dialogs, for which them triggering the event would be problematic, and ignore the others.

The other way of course would be to introduce a common abstract parent of all my view classes that does the above code.

Comment: Does this work when simply switching between two stages (without closing one)? Also, note that since JavaFX 9 there's a `Window.getWindows()` method that returns an `ObservableList<Window>`; it contains all showing windows at any given time. I think JavaFX 8 has a similar internal method.

Comment: Fair point, I didn't consider that. Most of my windows are modal (and all the problematic ones are) so this works for me. I guess I should have said so in the question. I guess we won't have a proper solution until they implement my enhancement request. About the API that list windows I'm pretty sure it exists, since TestFX can list them. I'll check how it does that when I'm back in the office Monday and post my findings here for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @Slaw I just figured out that your method returns an ObservableList so one can add a listener and automatically attach the window event listener to any new window, that's genius  I'll definitely check if the JavaFX 8 way returns an ObservableList as well, that would be great.

Comment: @Slaw Unfortunately, in JavaFX 8, you have to use the method Window.impl_getWindows(), which return an iterator and not an ObservableValue. I'll keep your suggestion in mind for when I'll be allowed to switch to Java 11 though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**JavaFX** hierarchy is based on: `Stage` -> `Scene` -> `Nodes` -> `...` -> `Nodes`:

[image]

If you want to listen focus of `Stage` (window), you can add listener to *Stage focused Property* of `Stage`:

```
Stage stage = ...
stage.focusedProperty()
        .addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                    if (!stage.isFocused()) { 
                       //action
                    }
                }
        );
```

> This doesn't solve the problem in the question. You can't tell here what component had the focus. `oldValue` and `newValue` are booleans, so your if is trivial

You can check that you all `Stage`s lost 
focuses (implement custom `ChangeListener`):

```
class AllStageUnfocusedListener implements ChangeListener<Boolean>{
    //IdentitySet and Runnable use only as example
    private final Set<Stage> stageSet;
    private final Runnable runnable;

    public AllStageUnfocusedListener(Runnable runnable) {
        this.stageSet =  Collections.newSetFromMap(new IdentityHashMap<>());
        this.runnable =  runnable;
    }

    public ChangeListener<Boolean> add(Stage stage){
        stageSet.add(stage);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
        if(isAllStageLostFocus()){
            runnable.run();
        }
    }

    private boolean isAllStageLostFocus() {
        for (Stage stage : stageSet) {
            if (stage.isFocused()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

and add `Listener` to `Focused Property`:

```
AllStageUnfocusedListener changeListener = new AllStageUnfocusedListener(() -> { /* action */ });
Stage stage = ...
stage.focusedProperty()
            .addListener(changeListener.add(stage))
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem in the question. You can't tell here what component had the focus. `oldValue` and `newValue` are `boolean`s, so your `if` is trivial.

Comment: Yes, you can tell what component had the focus, but you can tall that component lose it => **for example**: use collection `IdentitySet<Stage>`( `Collections.newSetFromMap( new IdentityHashMap<>()`) to add all `Stage`s to it and check that all lose the focus

Comment: This is better now after the edit. You will have to check for `Dialog` focus too, not only stages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I don't want to add listeners to all of my internal dialogs and windows, there are way too much of them...

Comment: Also your suggested code would only tell me it's the main window that has focus and none of the internal ones, it doesn't track who just lost focus. That would be pretty annoying to code because it would be time-based (had one of my windows lost focus in the last X milliseconds or something) and that kind of code is not reliable due to variance in performance on different desktops. Not counting the fact that I'd need to handle listener removal on internal windows closing to avoid memory leaks. It would become hard to maintain and I'm not alone in my team...